# JAVA BeanUtils.populate ERROR when leave empty date input

Tags: java, date, jboss, struts-1

Today I have migrated my application from JBOSS 4.2 to JBOSS 7.1. The server started successfully without any error messages. But when i try to submit any form where there is an inputs of "date from" and "date to" i got this error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: BeanUtils.populate
    org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:495)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:805)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:203)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.virc.spack.spring.UTF8Filter.doFilter(UTF8Filter.java:21)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.virc.spack.spring.SpringAccessFilter.doFilter(SpringAccessFilter.java:43)
JBWEB000071: root cause

org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException: No value specified for 'java.sql.Date'
    org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.AbstractConverter.handleMissing(AbstractConverter.java:327)
    org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.DateTimeConverter.convertToType(DateTimeConverter.java:327)
    org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.AbstractConverter.convert(AbstractConverter.java:169)
    org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.ConverterFacade.convert(ConverterFacade.java:61)
    org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.convert(ConvertUtilsBean.java:491)
    org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:1002)
    org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.populate(BeanUtilsBean.java:821)
    org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:431)
    org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:493)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:805)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:203)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.virc.spack.spring.UTF8Filter.doFilter(UTF8Filter.java:21)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.virc.spack.spring.SpringAccessFilter.doFilter(SpringAccessFilter.java:43)
```

The interesting part is that, if i enter "**date from**" and "**date to**" fields, for example (2014-05-01 and 2014-05-05) and submit a form, i dont get any error. But if i leave one of the fields empty for example (i leave empty field of "**date to**")  i get the error.

In Jboss 4.2 version witj JAVA 1.5 JDK everything was working perfectly, but after migration to Jboss 7.1 and Java 1.7 JDK i got these errors. Anyone knows any solutions?

Tell me if you need more info about what kind of libs are using and etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed in new version of BeanUtils-1.9
 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEANUTILS-454